# Multiple citations for same reference (Harvard)

Tags: citing, multiple-citations

In the case where I am referencing more than 1 instance of a website, I can't figure out how to show as:

(Flickr, 2017a) in the 1st instance AND (Flickr, 2017b) in the 2nd instance.

Currently, cited as \citep{Flickrb} and appears as (Flickr**b**, 2017) when compiled
BUT
Needs to read as (Flickr,2017**b**)

**Current User Package (Applied to all my other citations - single occurrences):**

```
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use the "Natbib" style for the references in the Bibliography
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}
```

**Current Bibliography.bib file it appears like this:**

```
@article{Flickrb,
author={Flickrb},
year={2017},
```

I thought it would just be a case of placing the letter after the year like this:

```
@article{Flickrb,
author={Flickr},
year={2017b},
```

But it outputs (Flickr, 017b) or something like that.
Also tried placing a comma after the year year={2017,b} and same result.

Does anyone by any chance know how to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Alan

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: Incidentally, what exactly are you trying to achieve by first specifying the options `numbers` and `square` (for numeric-style citation call-outs encased in square brackets) and then overriding these  options via the `\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}` directive? Why not load the `natbib` package directly with the options `round` and `authoryear`? Please advise.

Comment: You should think about it, is Flickr the author of what you want to cite? I know for sure that Stackexchange is not author of the comment i am just writing.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one entry with the same author(s) and publication year, just let `natbib` and LaTeX do the work for you. No need to affix "a", "b" etc in the raw bib entries.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{Smith:2017-further,
  author={Smith, John},
  title ={Mature Thoughts},
  year  ={2017},
  month =dec,
}
@misc{Smith:2017-beginner,
  author={Smith, John},
  Title ={Beginners' Thoughts},
  year  ={2017},
  month =feb,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round,authoryear,sort,comma]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike} % or whatever style you wish to use
\begin{document}
As shown by \citet{Smith:2017-further,Smith:2017-beginner}, \dots

As argued by others \citep[e.g.,][]{Smith:2017-further,Smith:2017-beginner}, \dots

\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```